# Laravel - ERROR: Trying to get property 'appraisal_name' of non-object

Tags: laravel

I have this code in Laravel-5.8

Controller

```
public function appraisal()
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $currentappraisal = AppraisalIdentity::select('appraisal_name', 'appraisal_start', 'appraisal_end')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();

    return view('appraisal-default')
            ->with('currentappraisal', $currentappraisal);        
}
```

view

```
            <center>
                <strong>
                    <span style="color:red;">NOTICE: Goal setting for the period {!! $currentappraisal->appraisal_name !!} starts on {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($currentappraisal->appraisal_start)->format('l jS \\of F Y') ?? '' }} and ends on {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($currentappraisal->appraisal_end)->format('l jS \\of F Y') ?? '' }}</span>
                </strong>
            </center>
```

I got this error:

> production.ERROR: Trying to get property 'appraisal_name' of non-object

because

> AppraisalIdentity:

is null.

How do I write a code to display None when it is null?

Thanks

Comment: `first` can return a record or `null`, in this case it didn't find a record so `null`, which isn't an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue displaying center element:

```
<center>
  <strong>
    <span style="color:red;">NOTICE: Goal setting for the period {!! isset($currentappraisal) ? $currentappraisal->appraisal_name : "" !!} starts on {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($currentappraisal->appraisal_start)->format('l jS \\of F Y') ?? '' }} and ends on {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($currentappraisal->appraisal_end)->format('l jS \\of F Y') ?? '' }}
    </span>
  </strong>
</center>
```

If element center shouldn't appear if $currentappraisal is null then

```
@if(isset($currentappraisal) && isset($currentappraisal->appraisal_name))
  <center>
    <strong>
      <span style="color:red;">NOTICE: Goal setting for the period {!! $currentappraisal->appraisal_name !!} starts on {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($currentappraisal->appraisal_start)->format('l jS \\of F Y') ?? '' }} and ends on {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($currentappraisal->appraisal_end)->format('l jS \\of F Y') ?? '' }}
      </span>
    </strong>
  </center>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
@if(isset($currentappraisal->appraisal_name))
    <center>
        <strong>
             <span style="color:red;">NOTICE: Goal setting for the period {!! $currentappraisal->appraisal_name !!} starts on {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($currentappraisal->appraisal_start)->format('l jS \\of F Y') ?? '' }} and ends on {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($currentappraisal->appraisal_end)->format('l jS \\of F Y') ?? '' }}
             </span>
         </strong>
     </center>
@endif
```